# Why does CORS reject requests with Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to wildcard?

Tags: cors

(Note - Edited title from "How do I resolve the CORS - No Allow Credentials error?")

---

I have an Angular front end making requests to an nginx back end.  Right now the nginx server is just returning a static response, but eventually it will proxy to a back end.  However I can't seem to get past a CORS error - Firefox reports "CORS No Allow Credentials" in the network tab.

The setup:

- Angular UI and nginx both running on my local machine from a docker compose
- Every request goes through nginx

  - UI requests are forwarded to "web-ui" (the Docker DNS will resolve to the Angular container)
  - Requests to "rest-api.mylocal.com" will give back a static JSON response from nginx
- /etc/hosts has been modified:

  - 127.0.0.1 rest-api.mylocal.com
  - 127.0.0.1 web-ui.mylocal.com

Basically - fire up a browser and point it at web-ui.mylocal.com, which will go through nginx and serve the Angular UI.  The angular app will then make a request from the browser to rest-api.mylocal.com, which is served from nginx.  The routing all works - I can see the requests and responses, but they are being denied by CORS.

The Angular service class looks like:

```
export class CCRestApiService {
  private REST_API_SERVER = "http://rest-api.mylocal.com";

  private _httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this._httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  public getFoo(authDomain: string){
    return this._httpClient.get(
      this.REST_API_SERVER + "/foo",
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
...
```

The nginx setup (the Docker daemon handles mapping 80->8080 on the host):

```
...
    upstream WEBUI {
       server web-ui:4200;
    }
...
    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        server_name web-ui.mylocal.com web-ui localhost;

        # Default
        location / {
            add_header Reverse-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://WEBUI;
        }
    }
...
    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        server_name rest-api.mylocal.com rest-api;

        location /foo {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            return 200 '{"status": "OK"}';
        }
    }
...
```

The request that gets sent from Angular:

```
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: rest-api.mylocal.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://web-ui.mylocal.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://web-ui.mylocal.com/
```

The response:

```
Status          200 OK
Version         HTTP/1.1
Transferred     356 B (34 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.4
Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 21:15:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 34
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

So - as near as I can tell, I've left the nginx server wide open, and definitely set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials.  So why is Firefox still balking with "CORS No Allow Credentials"?

Comment: Probably nothing to do with it, but it's a bad idea to use a real tld (.com).  From what I've seen in the RFC's they reserved a few including .localhost and .test insuring they would never be added to the root nameservers

Comment: fair - pretty much everything is being governed by either the host's /etc/hosts or the Docker DNS resolution.  And I was just randomly picking something so the two hosts would have the same root domain and could share cookies.  But I could change it.

Comment: It probably shouldn't matter, but since you're dealing with CORS issues.  Looking more carefully at what you are doing, I would suggest trying this substitution:  `add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $http_origin;`

Comment: wow... uh... so that worked...  Why doesn't the wildcard origin work...?  If you want to type that up as an answer, I'll give you credit for it though.  But seriously...  I was pretty sure wildcard was supposed to work?

Comment: I know this is a bit outdated, but the updated spec is a bit harder to navigate, and this shouldn't really have changed.  https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/#access-control-allow-origin says wildcard should be fine...  Really odd...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can get around this for now with:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $http_origin;
```

The [reason it does not work with your wildcard is discussed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials).

It's the combination of the wildcard and credentials that is the problem.

Just quoting from the MDN article:

> If, instead, you need to adjust the server's behavior, you'll need to
> change the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin to grant access to the
> origin from which the client is loaded.

[A really good article about CORS](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/what-is-cors/) and why attempting to set "...-Origin" to a wildcard doesn't work with any form of credential includes this pertinent quote:

> As mentioned earlier, setting `Access-control-allow-origin` to `*`
> effectively disables the same-origin policy. This means that the
> browser will allow almost any request to that cross-origin resource
> from any script that happens to be loaded. This might not seem so bad,
> because you trust all of the code you put on your site, right? But
> that's not the whole story, because the browser is now not filtering
> the origins, this means any code on any site (including malicious
> phishing sites) can actually make a request to that resource.
>
> Now, given that modern browsers are at least a little bit security
> conscious, if you did attempt to follow the wildcard copy-pasta that
> is all over popular forums and needed to use credentials such as
> Authorization HTTP headers or cookies, your cross-origin request will
> fail. This is because, in an attempt to at least partially fix this
> class of vulnerability, browsers don't allow you to set the
> `access-control-allow-credentials` header if the
> `access-control-allow-origins` is set to a wildcard.

So ultimately what you want is a policy that checks the origin and whitelists only the one(s) for your domain before then setting it to use the $http_origin.  This is a bit more complicated than you might think, given that pre-flight is involved, when the browser sends an OPTION request.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @gview - especially for the follow up around why the wildcard doesn't work.  Great work.